# JSON and JS Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback, jsonp

I'm having some problems understanding JS Callbacks in regards to getting and parsing JSON information.

What I'm trying to do is using this remote code to populate a select dropdown.

```
setCategories({
    "categories": ["Billing", "Gameplay", "Bugs", "Rules & Policies", "Technical Support"]
});
```

This code here above is coming from a remote .js file, this is the whole content of the file. I can't link to the file at this point.

Now I'm using what I know to access the JSON information

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/common/frontendtest/categories.js",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data: data,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
             console.log(data); //data returned

          }
        });
```

How ever this returns me this error message from the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setCategories is not defined

I know how to parse a simple json file, but this JS Callback is beyond my knowledge and I'm not sure how to work with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the function `setCategories` actually exist? If not, or if it's not global, that's your problem.

With jQuery it's better to let jQuery manage the name of JSON-P callbacks, but for cases where the web service is inflexible regarding the name of the callback function it expects, you can accommodate this via the `jsonpCallback` param when building your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    jsonpCallback: 'setCategories'
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that information, it helped a lot. You are a lifesaver. I'm not sure how this works but I have to dive more into this subject. Again THANK YOU!

Comment: No probs. JSON-P confuses a lot of people early on. I did a [detailed blog post on its workings](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JSON-P-what-what-s-not-and-how-works-205) a while back that should help you see what's going on.